# Create ActionBar Tabs with Fragments + viepage and recyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Hi all I am a noob with android so please bear with me on this!

I have used the below example to create a recyclerview with four tabbed fragments each displaying a list (card-view) of local teams I am creating an app for.

[Recyclerview example](https://github.com/delaroy/RecyclerViewFragment)

I am wanting to add an onclicklistener in each fragment and have tried using the if position method like I have done when I created a similar app some years ago but the get position method is depreciated.

I am aware that I can place onviewbind method in the adapter but I am told that this is not the best method, (I cannot get it to work) and the click listener should be placed in the fragment as this allows you to reuse the adapter which I will want to do as when someone makes a selection in one of the fragments I want to create another list in another fragment which will then include an expandable list.

My Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private String[] mDataset;

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public CardView mCardView;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public MyViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);

        mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

    }

}

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset){
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return mDataset.length; }
```

My Fragment

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"Example One", "Example Two", "Example Three", "Example Four", "Example Five" , "Example Six" , "Example Seven"});
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

I have tried various ways to get this working but I keep facing error or depreciated code.

Can anybody link me to a tutorial; that will help me or help me with some code to work this out!  Thanks In advance

Comment: what do you want to do ? you want to have a listener which will be notified when an item is clicked in the list ?

Comment: I want to start another activity when an item in the list is clicked, I then plan to create another list-view with expandable list using another adapter or the same adopter if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an interface in the Adapter like `onItemClickedListener` with method `onItemClicked(int position)` and a public method `setOnItemClickListener` in adapter to initialise the instance of `onItemClickedListener` in your adapter, from your fragment, and in `onBindViewHolder` add `setOnClickListener`, check if `onItemClickListener` is not null and then call the method `onItemClicked(int position)`, you code will look like this

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private String[] mDataset;

    private onItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    interface onItemClickListener{
        void onItemClicked(int position)
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener 
    onItemClickListener){
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public CardView mCardView;
        public TextView mTextView;

        public MyViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);

            mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

        }

    }

    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset){
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
        holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (onItemClickListener != null) {
                        onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(position);
                    }
                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return mDataset.length; }

    }
```

and your fragment will look like

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"Example One", "Example Two", "Example Three", "Example Four", "Example Five" , "Example Six" , "Example Seven"});
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.onItemClickListener){
             @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int pos) {
         // DO here what you want ot do on item clicked
            }
    });
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and it says cannot resolve method setonitemclicklistener anonymous view.view onclicklistener in myadapter and cannot resolve onclicklister in fragment

Comment: my bad, you have to setOnItemClickListener on the adapter and setOnClickListener in onBindViewHolder, i have fixed it

Comment: No problem I appreciate your help In the MyAdapter class it says intposition in the onbindviewholder should be set as final when I do this the code is OK but in fragment it is still saying on this line  adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener)  cannot resolve ontitemclicklistener.

Comment: ya if you want to use a variable in a interface implementation then it has to be final.

Comment: have you created the interface in MyAdapter,  `interface onItemClickListener{
        void onItemClicked(int position)
    }`

Comment: Yes I copied your code straight into the project also where it says public void onItemClicked(int pos) in fragment class it says it's expecting a ; or a {

Comment: you have to put a semicolan here   `holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (onItemClickListener != null) {
                        onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(position);
                    }
                }
        }); `

Comment: and  onItemClickListener starts with lowercase o,    `adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int position) {

            }
        });`

Comment: Thank you Rishabh I am grateful for your help I will try this tonight before I go to work and let you know bit I&#39;m sure I can figure this out from here.   Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: no problem at all, i also didn't tried it on studio, just wrote the answer before going to class so my bad, but now it will work fine

Comment: Hi This worked perfectly, but why is my intent not working, I assume I am using the incorrect intent  public void onItemClicked(int pos) {
                if (pos == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Bradford.class);
                    startActivity(intent);}  its saying   cannot resolve constructor

Comment: this here refers to onItemClickListener interface implementation, user getContext(); instead of this

Comment: I did realise I can't use .this inside an inner class I used getContext but it does appear to do anything,  I have added clickable true inside card view XML but it still is not working

Comment: click listener is set on textView only not the whole card view ? did you tried to click on textView